# Getting stderr post-mortem from still-running desktop graphical Java program?

Tags: java, swing, logging, stderr, postmortem-debugging

I am running a custom graphical Java application on my Windows desktop with jre 1.8.0_91.  I just had a failure that I think caused a custom JTable cell renderer to die.*  The program as a whole is still running.

Unfortunately, the code does not [log stderr](https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and) (but will as soon as I next work on the code!).  I started the jar from Windows Explorer, so there is no console and as far as I know stderr goes to the bit bucket.  (When I run the process from the command line, I get stderr on the terminal as usual.)

Is there any way to extract from my running Java process what if anything was most recently dumped to stderr?  Is there any Java-wide log file that might tell me?

---

*Symptoms, in case it matters: A custom-rendered table suddenly changed to a plain column view, with hashcodes instead of the rendered contents of the referenced objects (e.g., `CustomTable$TableEntry@1a2b3c`).  I can still interact with the table, which makes me think it's only the renderer that died.

Comment: Hmm. Reroute the Error stream to a text area?

Comment: @ifly6 I will do so next time I edit the code.  Unfortunately, the program doesn't do that now, and I'm hoping I can get some clues as to whatever my current bug is before I shut down the running process.

Comment: I doubt the renderer just dies. It is more likely you are changing the TableModel of the table and you did not reset the custom renderers.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for the lead!  I'll check into it.  It's an inherited codebase, and I don't know it 100%.  There's only one `model=...` and only one `setModel(model)` call, but the data in the model certainly do change at runtime.  If I can reproduce and get an MCVE I'll post a question.